# Do community wikis give some people what they don't deserve, but not let some people get what they do?

Tags: discussion, reputation, badges, community-wiki

Here is a post that is an ideal Community Wiki: [What browsers support HTML5 WebSocket API?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2700609/2846923). People have collaborated, and the original owner of the post is the author of only 53% of it. Yet he still got Great Answer, Good Answer, Necromancer, Teacher, and Nice Answer from it, as well as a nice 311 score answer on his user page.

Now, that's about somebody getting stuff they possibly don't completely deserve. What about somebody *not* getting stuff they probably *do* deserve? Here are two opposite, but in a way the same, examples:

- [3ventic](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/51318/3ventic) wrote an answer that is a CW: [What are the types of bag loot items and how much are they worth?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/129479/64041). He specifically ["made [it] community wiki so other people would contribute."](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/1944193#1944193) However, [nobody else contributed anything](https://i.3ventic.eu/20140402222017428.png). Reputation deserved: 60. Reputation obtained: 10.
- [poundifdef](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3788/poundifdef) wrote an answer that is a CW: [Instead of NULL, should I write `0x0` or `0`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1765202/2846923). He specifically abused community wikifying to avoid negative reputation:

  > **edit2**

  > well, it looks like i've missed the mark on this one! sorry! (CW'd. feel free to keep downvoting!)

  Reputation deserved: probably -20. Reputation obtained: -8.

Is this a problem? What should be done about it?

Answer (score 2):

Reputation is not rewarded to CW posts already, so most of the reward is removed. Consider any badges that result for the original author of a CW post to be a bonus for getting the thing started.

As for people "not getting what they deserve," I don't see it that way. When you contribute by editing someone else's answer, you already know you're not going to share in the reputation and badges for that post. Making the post CW doesn't change a thing about that arrangement.

Comment: If the point of a CW not giving reputation is because the owner doesn't deserve the rep from a collaboration, shouldn't the owner still get rep if it  _isn't_ a collaboration (i.e. nobody else edits the post)?

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat Then why would it be a CW post?

Comment: Because someone _wanted_ it to be a collaboration. In the example in the question, I specifically noted that 3ventic made it a CW so others would contribute.

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat The author chose to make it a *community wiki* post. You can't force it to be a collaboration. I don't think we need to complicate the rules of CW. They've only just recently been simplified.